# how to sum value of every last date based on product code in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

```html
table :

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>product_code</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>value</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>a1</td>
<td>2023-01-21</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a1</td>
<td>2023-01-19</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a1</td>
<td>2023-01-18</td>
<td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b1</td>
<td>2023-01-20</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b1</td>
<td>2023-01-18</td>
<td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c1</td>
<td>2023-01-19</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c1</td>
<td>2023-01-20</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

result : 

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>product_code</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>value</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>a1</td>
<td>2023-01-21</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>b1</td>
<td>2023-01-20</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c1</td>
<td>2023-01-20</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>


sum value 20+20+20 = 60
```

table :

```
product_code        date            value
a1              2023-01-21           20
a1              2023-01-19           10
a1              2023-01-18           30
b1              2023-01-20           20
b1              2023-01-18           30
c1              2023-01-19           10
c1              2023-01-20           20
```

result :

```
product_code      date              value
a1            2023-01-21           20
b1            2023-01-20           20
c1            2023-01-20           20
```

then sum value 20+20+20 = 60

table :

```
product_code        date            value
a1              2023-01-21           20
a1              2023-01-19           10
a1              2023-01-18           30
b1              2023-01-20           20
b1              2023-01-18           30
c1              2023-01-19           10
c1              2023-01-20           20
```

result :

```
product_code      date              value
a1            2023-01-21           20
b1            2023-01-20           20
c1            2023-01-20           20
```

then sum value 20+20+20 = 60

Comment: This is sum most recent order by group? Also, where is the PHP part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Assumed the table name is **products** - this is a query that sum the **value** of the most recent record per group

**Query Builder query:**

```
DB::table('products as p1')
    ->select('p1.*')
    ->leftJoin('products as p2', function ($query) {
        $query->where('p2.product_code', '=', DB::raw('p1.product_code'))
            ->where('p2.date', '>', DB::raw('p1.date'));
    })
    ->whereNull('p2.date')
    ->sum('p1.value');
```

**SQL Query:**

```
select SUM(p1.value) as total from products as p1 left join products as p2 on p2.product_code = p1.product_code and p2.date > p1.date where p1.date is null;
```

Comment: thank you sir, but i want the result is evey product value only last date (latest)
a1 2023-01-21 20 ---> last date a1 = 2023-01-21 with value 20 (latest date of a1)
b1 2023-01-20 20 ---> last date b1 = 2023-01-20 with value 20 (latest date of b1)
c1 2023-01-20 20 ---> last date c1 = 2023-01-20 with value 20 (latest date of c1)

then sum value of latest date each product = 20+20+20 = 60

thankyou

Comment: Do you mean, you want to retrieve records first which have the latest date? and after that, do you want to sum of retrieved records? right?

Comment: no sir... i just want to sum value of latest date each product. thank you

Comment: Yes, In that query you will get a sum of the latest date of each product code. Are you run this piece of code to get the sum?

Comment: Found a mistake in my code and updated it. Try again with the updated code.